# get python result from ajax error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

i'm trying get python result from ajax

my code : web

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.py",
                    success: function(response){
                            alert(response);
                    }
            });

    </script>
```

python

```
print("hello! result get!")
```

but i execute this code
result is

result of this code
[image]

Instead, visible results is code

what is wrong in this code?

**SOLVED!**
**EDIT**

enable apache cgi mode then solve!

Comment: Have you set up your web server to execute python scripts and return the results?  It looks like it's just returning the literal contents of the py file.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the ajax code. It's doing exactly what it is supposed to